# NServiceBus - should command and respective handler be in the same namespace?

Tags: c#, nservicebus

I have 2 microservices communicating with each other via NServiceBus. Let's say SVC1 sends a command to SVC2 which in response do something and emits some events (which eventually subscribed by other services including SVC1).

I have separate contract assembly for keeping Event/Commands/Messages types inside each services (viz SVC1, SVC2).

Now when a given command lets say CMD1 saved inside SVC1 solution (which is triggering this command BTW) and handled by SVC2, I am getting NServieBus no destination found which is self-explanatory that NServiceBus could not register respective handlers for the given command CMD1.

So my question is that, is it mandatory to keep the command types and it's handler in same namespace?

When i looked into my custom code which is finding all the types (of type commands) for registering it inside NServiceBus it just simply loading all the assemblies at the given path and ofcourse SVC2 had reference added of CMD1 then it simply fail to register it?

Thanks in advance and sorry for asking such a naive question.

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is that, is it mandatory to keep the command types and it's handler in same namespace?

No, namespace has nothing to do with who owns what.

> I have separate contract assembly for keeping Event/Commands/Messages types inside each services (viz SVC1, SVC2).

It's probably better to create separate assemblies for different messages and not keep them inside the assembly where your handlers are also in.

[This sample](https://docs.particular.net/samples/unobtrusive/) shows how to use messages, except that all messages are in a single shared assembly. They are in the namespace `Messages` and not in a namespace the endpoint is in. Use this sample and split out the different messages into different assemblies to see if you can get that working.